# determine position of circle inside square

Tags: geometry, circles

i need to determine position of circle inside  square,let us suppose that we have following picture

[image]

we have following informations:

1.$ABCD$ is square

2.all small figures ,$KMCE$,$PKEF$,$NPFD$ are square as well

3.diamter of small circle is equal to $6$ cm

problem:

we have to find area of    $ABCD$ square

problem what i have is that  i dont know  how  to express  small  sides of small  squares in terms of diameter or radius or even  find relationship  between big square and  circle.clearly  it is not obvious that center of circle is located on intersection points of diagonals,please help me  ,maybe  it is very simple and i  dont see key fact,but please give me  a hint and i will try to get point of main idea  of solution of this problem.thanks in advance

Comment: You should try to express the side of the small squares as a function of the side of the big square, then you can deduce $BM$, which is equal to the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the sidelength of the small square $a$. Then, $|CD| = 3a$. This implies $|AD| = 3a$, and $|AN| = |AD|-|DN| = 2a$. The diameter of the small circle is thus $2a$. Now, solve $2a = 6$ to find $a$, and ...

Comment: ui so simple,i think it is morning and brain has not  working yet properly :D

Comment: I recommend coffee :)

Comment: :D   yes  you are right,better Jacobs Monarch :D

Answer (score 1):

Area of Square is 81 cm*cm

Solution-->

```
 suppose ND=m then PF=KE=CM=ND   (because all PF, KE, CM, ND all four line inside parallel line MN and CD)
```

now we can say

```
 AD=6+m   ------eq(1)
 CB=6+m   ------eq(2)
```

now

```
  CD=m+m+m
  CD=3m    ------eq(3)
```

we know that

```
 AD=CD      (lines of square)

6+m=3m
3m-m=6
2m=6
m=3
```

now put the value of m in eq(1)

```
AD=6+m=6+3=9
AD=9
AD=CD=BC=AB=9

Area of Square is 
   AD*AD =9*9=81 cm*cm
hence area of give square is 81 cm*cm
```